# Manual control over placement of contour labels in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

Sometimes the automatic placement of `pgfplots`'s contour labels is not satisfactory. For example, consider this example from the manual (with minor changes),

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-2:2,view={0}{90}]
  \addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=14,label distance=10000pt},thick]
    {exp(0-x^2-y^2)*x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Now I simply change the upper limit of the x-axis to -0.75,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=-2:2,view={0}{90},xmax=-0.75]
  \addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=14,label distance=10000pt},thick]
    {exp(0-x^2-y^2)*x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Now the contour label positions coincide with the right y-axis and are therefore invisible. Of course, I could increase `xmax` and/or lower the value of `label distance` to get more labels. However, in my real problem (not the above MWE) I cannot increase `xmax` (it represents the maximum value of the independent variable) and I think in general a smaller number of labels looks better. It seems to me that in this case it would be better if the labels were placed either

1. along y=0 or
2. along the line (-1,1.6) -- (-0.75,0).

Which brings me to my question: Can I specify manually the position of contour labels and if so, how?

(This may seem crazy when using `gnuplot` to generate the contours, but in general I use my own tool and the `contour prepared` option, so I could compute the position of the labels quite easily. The angle should also be possible, though perhaps a little more challenging for poorly resolved contour levels.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody posted an answer or a comment, I thought I'd briefly outline the work-around I developed. Perhaps it will be useful for somebody although the work-around is not automated.

As alluded to at the end of my question, I amended my code to extract isolines so it can also write out labels. For simplicity, I assume that they are placed at the intersection points of one or more straight lines and the isolines. The amended code writes out a file with the labels as nodes, i.e.,

```
\node[align=center,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny,rotate=  46.3] at (axis cs: 0.132129E+01,-0.914058E+00) {0.1};
```

which I then `input` into the file with the `TikZ/pgfplots` commands. The angle can be computed automatically from the slope of the isolines where it intersects the straight line with the labels.

For the example function from the `pgfplots` manual, this is the result:

[image]

In my opinion, this looks better than the automated placement of labels by `pgfplots`, but it is more interactive and requires the use of the `contour prepared` option. One thing that is missing is the matching of the color of the contour label to that of the contour itself…

Comment: Please add a fully functional example code to your answer.