# How to match color of user-placed labels to contours in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

This question is a follow-up to [this one about manually placing contour labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285213/manual-control-over-placement-of-contour-labels-in-pgfplots) in `pgfplots` contour plots produced with the `contour prepared` option. Briefly put, the problem I'm faced with now is that the manually placed contour labels are all in black (or any other color I want) and do not match the color of the contour lines. For example, see:

[image]

So my question is: How do I modify the files below so that the label colors match the color of the contour lines as they would if the labels had been generated by `pgfplots`?

What I'm looking for in the solution:

1. For obvious reasons, I would like the color matching to be automatic and not have to be done by hand. Based on the `pgfplots` manual, this would appear to require something using `mapped color!50!black` but I have not been able to get this to work.
2. It would be great if the solution would also work if I decided to skip labeling every contour line (for example, if they are equispaced and close to each other). (To be specific, if I were to label only the 0.5 and 1.5 levels in the plot above, the colors should remain blue and red - the 1.5 level should not be orange because the 1.0 level was skipped.)

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,
    label/.style={align=center,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny}]
    \begin{axis}[width=5.0cm,height=5.0cm,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0]
      \input{contour-data.tex}
      \input{contour-labels.tex}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is `data.tex`:

```
\addplot[contour prepared={labels=false}]
table {
  0.500000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00
  0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00

  0.100000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01
  0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01
  0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.100000E+01

  0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.150000E+01
  0.100000E+01  0.500000E+00  0.150000E+01 
};
```

And here is `labels.tex`:

```
\node[label,rotate=-45.0] at (axis cs: 0.250000E+00, 0.250000E+00) {0.5};
\node[label,rotate=-45.0] at (axis cs: 0.500000E+00, 0.500000E+00) {1.0};
\node[label,rotate=-45.0] at (axis cs: 0.750000E+00, 0.750000E+00) {1.5};
```

Comment: Why placing the labels in a separate file when you can automatically have them?

Comment: Because, as I explained in my previous question, the automatic placement does not always work very well. As I also stated, the manual placement is more interactive and therefore less convenient, but in many cases the additional flexibility leads to more visually pleasing output (IMHO).

Comment: But as you can see in the answer below, it works quite well. :)

Comment: I don't understand your comment - the answer below does not make use of the automatic placement of the labels…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to wonder, where the colors are chosen from. They come from the actual colormap, which by default is `colormap name=hot`. This can be visualized easily when activating the `colorbar`. You will find a lot of `colormaps` in the manual or even can create one yourself, if you want.

With the new release of PGFPlots v1.13 it is easy to pick a color from the `colormap` with the key `color of colormap` which can be found in section 4.7.6 on page 193 of the manual. The drawback is, that the number is expected to be in the interval [0,1000] so you "manually" have to compute it from the z or meta values. Here is the code using this new feature.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        label/.style={
            align=center,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny,
            %% adds additional space in front of the text which has exactly the
            %% size of "!50!white" and is considered being a bug.
            %% (To verify that this length is added, uncomment the last node
            %%  at the end of the axis and you will notice, that the "1.5"s
            %%  are overlapping each other.)
            %text=.!40!white,     % <-- `.' equals the actual color
            %
            % to avoid this bug, just turn the color definition around
            text=white!60!.,     % <-- `.' equals the actual color
        },
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=5.0cm,height=5.0cm,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0,
            colorbar,           % just to show where the colors come from
            colormap/viridis,   % <-- change colormap
            % change min and max values of the colorbar
            point meta min=0,point meta max=2,
        ]
            \addplot[contour prepared={labels=false,}] table {
                0.500000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00
                0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00

                0.100000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01
                0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01
                0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.100000E+01

                0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.150000E+01
                0.100000E+01  0.500000E+00  0.150000E+01
            };

            \node[color of colormap=250,label,rotate=-45.0]
                at (0.250000E+00, 0.250000E+00) {0.5};
            \node[color of colormap=500,label,rotate=-45.0]
                at (0.500000E+00, 0.500000E+00) {1.0};
            \node[color of colormap=750,label,rotate=-45.0]
                at (0.750000E+00, 0.750000E+00) {1.5};

            %% to show the bug, uncomment the folowing lines and switch
            %% to the other `text' key in the definition of the `label' style
            %\node[align=center,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny,rotate=-45.0]
            %    at (0.750000E+00, 0.750000E+00) {!40!white1.5};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

To avoid doing this manual calculation the "New Answer" of Symbol 1 is probaply the best you can get.

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I'm looking for… (I don't mind the manual calculation since I can automate it with the code I wrote to place the labels.) The only thing that is missing is how I can blend the color of the labels with a little black to prevent the labels from becoming invisible if the contour color is very light (yellow, for example). That is, how do I implement the `text=mapped color!50!black` from @Symbol 1's answer in your answer? I tried modifying the statements `text=.` and `color of colormap=250` by adding `50!black` but this did not work...

Comment: Hopefully you meant that you added `!50!black` which than gives in total `text=.!50!black`. This is the solution you are searching for. Unfortunately there seems to be a bug doing that way round. I have updated my above answer where you can show the bug and the possible "workaround". (I have chosen to use white instead, because in my example the colors are very dark already.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Great, this is now just what I'm looking for, thanks. (Now I hope the bug in PGF relating to `heightof` will be fixed soon so I can use `pgfplots` v1.13 in TeXLive 2015 not just for this figure but for all my figures. I reported the bug sourceforge already (mistakenly believing it was a `pgfplots` bug).)

Answer (score 10):

## New Answer

This is pure PGFPLOTS answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    label/.style={
        nodes={font=\tiny,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,text=mapped color,#1},
        point meta=explicit,nodes near coords*,nodes near coords align=
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=5.0cm,height=5.0cm,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0]
        \addplot[contour prepared={labels=false}]table {
            0.500000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00
            0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00

            0.100000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01
            0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01
            0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.100000E+01

            0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.150000E+01
            0.100000E+01  0.500000E+00  0.150000E+01
        };
        \addplot[label={rotate=-45}]coordinates{(0.250000E+00, 0.250000E+00)[0.5]};
        \addplot[label={rotate=-45}]coordinates{(0.500000E+00, 0.500000E+00)[1.0]};
        \addplot[label={rotate=-45}]coordinates{(0.750000E+00, 0.750000E+00)[1.5]};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The key point is that the color is available as `mapped color` if the color-calculation is turned on. So by `point meta=explicit` I trigger the color-calculation. Then by `nodes near coords*` I have a node showing the meta value, which is `0.5`, `1.0`, `1.5` in your question. Finally `nodes near coords align` aligns the node properly.

Notice that `1.0` is shown as `1` because the default of `nodes near coords*` is (line 2859 in `pgfplots.code.tex`.)

> ```
> nodes near coords*/.default={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
> ```

Where `\pgfplotspointmeta` is a FPU-number and `\pgfmathprintnumber` has its own format. You can alter this by something like

```
nodes near coords*={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill]\pgfplotspointmeta}
```

## Update

To gain the control of explicit output, you need tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    label/.style={
        nodes={font=\tiny,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,text=mapped color!50!black,#1},
        point meta=\thisrow{color},nodes near coords*={\mylabel},nodes near coords align=,
        visualization depends on=value \thisrow{label}\as\mylabel,
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=5.0cm,height=5.0cm,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0]
        \addplot[contour prepared={labels=false}]table {
            0.500000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00
            0.000000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00

            0.100000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01
            0.500000E+00  0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01
            0.000000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.100000E+01

            0.500000E+00  0.100000E+01  0.150000E+01
            0.100000E+01  0.500000E+00  0.150000E+01
        };
        \addplot[label={rotate=-45}]table{
            x            y            color label
            0.250000E+00 0.250000E+00 0.5   {0.50}
        };
        \addplot[label={rotate=-45}]table{
            x            y            color label
            0.500000E+00 0.500000E+00 1.0   {the one!}
        };
        \addplot[label={rotate=-45}]table{
            x            y            color label
            0.750000E+00 0.750000E+00 1.5   {$\frac32$}
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## About Old Answer

PGFPLOTS is hard to understand. So I firstly came up with this pure-Ti*k*Z approach. I said **"This is a working example"** because the approach is rather tedious: A `\spy` copies the whole `axis` environment once. Now ask yourself how many labels there are going to be.

## Old Answer Below

This is a working example. Perhaps you can automate the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,spy}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{label/.style={circle,minimum size=10,circle,text=transparent,fill=transparent!0,font=\tiny}}
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=label no 1]
        \path(0,0)node[rotate=-45,label]{0.5};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=label no 2]
        \path(0,0)node[rotate=-45,label]{1.0};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=label no 3]
        \path(0,0)node[rotate=-45,label]{1.5};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[spy scope={circle,magnification=20,size=15}]
            \begin{axis}[width=5.0cm,height=5.0cm,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0]
                \input{data.tex}
                \coordinate(coord no 1)at(axis cs: 0.750000E+00, 0.750000E+00);
                \coordinate(coord no 2)at(axis cs: 0.500000E+00, 0.500000E+00);
                \coordinate(coord no 3)at(axis cs: 0.250000E+00, 0.250000E+00);
                \spy on(coord no 1)in node at(coord no 1);
                \spy on(coord no 2)in node at(coord no 2);
                \spy on(coord no 3)in node at(coord no 3);
            \end{axis}
        \end{scope}
        \fill[white,path fading=label no 1](coord no 1)circle(25pt);
        \fill[white,path fading=label no 2](coord no 2)circle(25pt);
        \fill[white,path fading=label no 3](coord no 3)circle(25pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Decomposition

Use `spy` library to magnified the line. This step guarantees that the colors match.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[spy scope={circle,magnification=20,size=15}]
        \begin{axis}[width=5.0cm,height=5.0cm,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0]
            \input{data.tex}
            \coordinate(coord no 1)at(axis cs: 0.750000E+00, 0.750000E+00);
            \coordinate(coord no 2)at(axis cs: 0.500000E+00, 0.500000E+00);
            \coordinate(coord no 3)at(axis cs: 0.250000E+00, 0.250000E+00);
            \spy on(coord no 1)in node at(coord no 1);
            \spy on(coord no 2)in node at(coord no 2);
            \spy on(coord no 3)in node at(coord no 3);
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then prepare the "mask"

[image]

```
\tikz\path(0,0)node[rotate=-45,label,fill=black,text=white]{0.5};
\tikz\path(0,0)node[rotate=-45,label,fill=black,text=white]{1.0};
\tikz\path(0,0)node[rotate=-45,label,fill=black,text=white]{1.5};
```

The "mask" should be white (black part should be white). And the text is punched out (white part should be transparent). This is implemented by `fadings` library.

[image]

```
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=label no 1]
    \path(0,0)node[rotate=-45,label]{0.5};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\tikz{
    \shade[shading=color wheel](0,0)rectangle(2,2);
    \fill[white,path fading=label no 1](1,1)circle(75pt);
}
```

Now combine them all together.

## Appendix

Playing with opacity, one can have the label color slightly darker than the line color.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[spy scope={circle,magnification=20,size=15}]
        \begin{axis}[width=5.0cm,height=5.0cm,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0]
            \input{data.tex}
            \coordinate(coord no 1)at(axis cs: 0.750000E+00, 0.750000E+00);
            \coordinate(coord no 2)at(axis cs: 0.500000E+00, 0.500000E+00);
            \coordinate(coord no 3)at(axis cs: 0.250000E+00, 0.250000E+00);
            \spy on(coord no 1)in node at(coord no 1);
            \spy on(coord no 2)in node at(coord no 2);
            \spy on(coord no 3)in node at(coord no 3);
        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}
    \fill[black,opacity=.5](coord no 1)circle(5pt);
    \fill[black,opacity=.5](coord no 2)circle(5pt);
    \fill[black,opacity=.5](coord no 3)circle(5pt);
    \fill[white,path fading=label no 1](coord no 1)circle(25pt);
    \fill[white,path fading=label no 2](coord no 2)circle(25pt);
    \fill[white,path fading=label no 3](coord no 3)circle(25pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the detailed explanation of the various steps. (There's a small mistake in that the labels 0.5 and 1.5 are switched.) It seems quite involved, which leaves me wondering whether there might be an easier way. I don't understand the inner workings of pgfplots, but it seems that there's a predefined range of colors (blue to red) from which the colors of the isolines are determined, presumably by interpolating between the minimum (blue) and the maximum (red). Why is it not possible to do the same or something similar for the isoline labels?

Comment: @Symbol 1: Your "New Answer" is the best one get when separating plotting and labeling, because it also works when changing the colormap and/or the `point meta' min and max values. Great!

Comment: Thanks for your new answer. I have two questions: 1. How can I mix the `mapped color` with a certain percentage of black (as is done if the labels are placed automatically)? 2. Would it be possible to change the code so that the specified labels keep their precision rather than being truncated? Your suggestion to change `pgfplots.code.tex` is not attractive because different plots require different precision for the labels.)

Comment: @user1362373 the first question is quite direct: change `text=mapped color` to `text=mapped color!50!black` or something else. For second question... wait a minute,

Comment: @user1362373 I updated.