# How to resolve conflict between versions of TeXLive and pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texlive

To resolve the problem I described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285483/how-to-match-color-of-user-placed-labels-to-contours-in-pgfplots), I need to use `pgfplots` version 1.13, which required that I updated to TeX Live 2015. Doing so lead to a problem with the command `\heightof` as can be seen by running the MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text height=\heightof{$\pi/2$}] {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which leads to

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@text@height ->\heightof 
                              {$\pi /2$}
l.5 \node[text height=\heightof{$\pi/2$}] {Text};
```

So I need TeX Live 2015 for some of my figures, but this breaks other figures, which work fine with TeX Live 2014. I have already reported this problem on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/93/) - originally believing it to be a `pgfplots` problem - where Christian Feuersänger pointed out that it's actually a problem with `pgf`.

As of today, the bug report is still open, which - I want to make this very clear - I am **not** complaining about. Instead, I want to ask one practical and one less practical question. The practical one:

How can I get around both problems until the bug is fixed? I'm happy with a kludgy workaround, but I would like to avoid having to process my figures in two groups according to whether they need TeX Live 2015 or 2014. The reason is twofold. First, my document is rather large (100s of `.tex` files). Second, it is processed with several Makefiles.

My less practical question arose out of my curiosity and experience with developing and testing complex software: Do new versions of `pgf`, TikZ, and `pgfplots` undergo automated regression testing before they are released (and incorporated into TeX Live, for example)? It appears not, but I find this odd given the background of Till Tantau and Christian Feuersänger in Computer Science and Numerical Simulation, so I must assume I am wrong and that they do undergo automated regression testing. Am I missing something?

Let me state again that I am **not** complaining about `pgf` and `pgfplots`. I am very grateful for them and enjoy the high-quality figures they allow me to produce.

Comment: `\heightof` is a macro from `calc` package. But it won't work even with `\usepackage{calc}` (at least not this way)

Comment: Note that while it's convenient to talk about 'TeX Live <year>', the majority of the code is not written by the TL team nor updated only once per year. That _is_ (broadly) true for the engine binaries (so `pdftex`, _etc._) but not for individual packages. Here, the rest of TL has nothing to do with the issue, which is as noted due to the fact `calc` is needed to define `\heightof`. Presumably internal changes in `pgf` mean this is no longer loaded (and indeed adding it manually doesn't solve the issue, so there must be other changes). However, that's not the fault of the TL team or other ...

Comment: ... package authors. Each package author is free to define their own release schedule, testing approach and so on. (For the core LaTeX team work there _is_ a test suite and we do pay close attention to the TL cycle. However, that's atypical. You can't even assume that the _engines_ get regression tested, as it's not unknown for the LaTeX test suite to find all sorts of interesting thing!)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I know that the TL team does not develop the majority of the code and that it is updated more than once a year. I am not looking to blame anyone. I am simply wondering whether `pgf`, TikZ, and `pgfplots`, and, by extension, TL, undergo automated regression testing before they are released. If they are not, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I did not need the `calc` package with TeXLive 2014.

Comment: @user1362373 As I've said, testing for each package is down to the relevant authors (so the link to TL is really not important: remember there are other TeX systems). Most LaTeX packages aren't tested beyond actually being used and partly as writing the tests is not trivial, partly as most are written by non-professional programmers (or indeed 'non-programmers').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

guessing the intended meaning, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newlength\zzz
\settoheight\zzz{$\pi/2$}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text height=\zzz] {Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All true but this did work with the last TL2014 version of `pgf`, so presumably a change between `pgf` 3.0.0 and 3.0.1a involved dropping support for `\heightof` inside expressions.

Comment: @JosephWright yes but the question was how to work around the issue not how to debug pgf internals:-) making the above change makes the document work...

Comment: The reason why I use `\heightof` is that I want to align tick labels on the same baseline. (For example, `\pi`, `\pi/2`, etc.) Is the solution you suggest formally identical to the MWE or are there any subtleties that could lead to later problems? I'm asking because your workaround would mean that I convert all my figures using `\heightof`.

Answer (score 5):

There has been a significant change in the definition of the internal macro `\pgfmathparse@`. The older version includes a set of compatibility lines for use with `calc` which have (presumably deliberately) been removed. Adding those back in but otherwise keeping the new definition gives

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathparse@#1{%
    % Stuff for calc compatiability.
    \let\real=\pgfmath@calc@real
    \let\minof=\pgfmath@calc@minof
    \let\maxof=\pgfmath@calc@maxof
    \let\ratio=\pgfmath@calc@ratio
    \let\widthof=\pgfmath@calc@widthof
    \let\heightof=\pgfmath@calc@heightof
    \let\depthof=\pgfmath@calc@depthof
    % No (math) units yet. 
    \global\pgfmathunitsdeclaredfalse
    \global\pgfmathmathunitsdeclaredfalse
    % Expand expression so any reamining CSs are registers
    % or box dimensions (i.e. |\wd|, |\ht|, |\dp|).
    \edef\pgfmath@expression{#1}%
        %
        \expandafter\pgfmathparse@trynumber@loop\pgfmath@expression\pgfmath@parse@stop
        %
        % this here is the _real_ parser. it is invoked by
        % \pgfmathparse@trynumber@loop if that says "this is no number"
        %\pgfmathparse@@\pgfmath@parse@stop%
}
\makeatother
```

where the set added are those at the start.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that I put this into a file and `\input` it while I'm using TL 2015? (This worked for the MWE.)

Comment: @user1362373 I'm suggesting you put it in your source files marked up as a 'temporary patch' until it's addressed by the `pgf` maintainers. If you want to be cautious you could use `\@ifpackagelater` to only patch the latest release.

Comment: Instead of redefining `\pgfmathparse@` I would recommend using `\pretocmd{\pgfmathparse@}{\let....}{}{}`, so that other further changes of `\pgfmathparse@` are applied. (However, I could not test it, as I don't have the current texlive installed)